# How to know if the system is running a live or an installed version?

Tags: live-usb

What command can provide information to discern if the actual running version has been launched from a live installation on, say, a pen, or a full installation in the hard drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on live-usb, when command `mount` returns:

```
aufs on / type aufs
```

and then commands `users` and `hostname` returns:

```
ubuntu
```

Comment: Oddly enough, for me it was `overlayfs`

Answer (score 2):

You can check the options set for the kernel, which will probably include `casper`:

```
grep -zq casper /proc/cmdline && echo live
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to execute a command, just open a terminal.

If you are on an installation media you'll see : `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$`

On a running installed system you'll see : `<user>@<hostname>:~$`

Here the example from my installed Ubuntu OS : `cl@cl-uw-1:~$`

Comment: This might be challenging if full installation has the name ubuntu and a user named ubuntu.

Comment: @atayenel : hahaha ... yes indeed ... when you choose the name ubuntu as user and host for the installed system, then of course you won't see a difference and no command can't help and won't change a thing. :)